# window.print() not working inside useeffect (or anywhere on page)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am trying to call window.print() and nothing happens.  In the same place, I try window.alert('test') and it works.

any ideas?

a different page in my application does successfully call window.print() so I'm thinking it's not a printing setting on my machine

Comment: Make a function call from hooks and write the window.print() in that function . it may work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

window.print was being blocked by an  element on the page.

I got it to work using the react-to-print.   If you look at the code behind react to print, you'll see it doesn't quite use window.print, rather some other thing like (target.contentWindow.print();). And in the readme of it, you can see it was explicitly created for scenarios where window.print was blocked - like firefox.  [image]

Implementation of this is like this:

1. add a useRef variable and set it to an element on the page (either a div perhaps or else a component.
2. 

const componentRef = useRef();
const handlePrint = useReactToPrint({ content: () => componentRef.current!})

```
<div css={{ display: 'none', '@media print': { display: 'block' } }} ref={componentRef}> <CoversheetPrint {...coversheetData} />         
</div>
```

https://github.com/gregnb/react-to-print/search?q=window.print